# Can a batsman be out "Hit the ball twice" of a no-ball in cricket?

Tags: cricket

I was not able to google even a single instance of out "Hit the ball twice" in cricket.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit_the_ball_twice) doesn't mention no-ball. [This link](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-24-no-ball/) says that the batsman can be out "Hit the ball twice" of a no-ball.

Few Doubts:

1. Can a batsman be out "Hit the ball twice of a no-ball"?

   If Yes :
2. How many runs can be scored of the no-ball?
3. Next ball should ideally be a free hit?
4. Has it ever happened in the history of cricket?

Comment: Ask one question per post.

Comment: @MaskedMan aren't these the part of the same question. Its a single question with related sub questions. Sub questions are not as important to be posted as several questions.

Comment: The link you've given is to the official Laws of cricket. What source are you looking for which would remove your doubts?

Comment: It's clear what you're asking, but as Philip Kendall says, you won't get a clearer reference than the Laws of Cricket. The other questions should be asked separately, especially as they refer to various forms of the game, plus a question that could be answered by searching on Cricinfo

Comment: @TrueDub To me, it is unclear what OP is asking because he is apparently aware that a batsman can be out HTBT of a no-ball, and then asks again if this can happen. It is also not clear why he is asking Q3, because he has not explained why he thinks the next ball after a no-ball may *not* be a free hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was not able to google even a single instance of out "Hit the ball twice" in cricket.

You didn't try very hard! The [Wikipedia page for "Hit the ball twice"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit_the_ball_twice) lists two examples.

> Can a batsman be out "Hit the ball twice of a no-ball"?

Yes. You yourself linked to the [offical Laws of cricket](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-24-no-ball/) which state:

> 16. When No ball has been called, neither batsman shall be out under any of the Laws except [...] 34 (Hit the ball twice)

That seems about as clear as it could be written.

> How many runs can be scored of the no-ball?

One run will be scored for the no ball. I'm struggling to imagine a realistic situation in which the batsmen can complete a run before the striker hits the ball for a second time - note that once a fielder has touched the ball, a batsman *cannot* be out hit the ball twice. [Law 37 (Obstructing the field)](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-37-obstructing-the-field/) explicitly includes the fact that runs made before the dismissal will count, but there is no such mention in [Law 34](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-34-hit-the-ball-twice/), so I think this is somewhat undefined in the Laws.

> Next ball should ideally be a free hit?

Free hits are not part of the Laws of Cricket, but instead part of the playing conditions for various tournaments, so it is not possible to give a generic answer to this question. However, a dismissal does not stop the free hit from occurring under the current ODI or T20 International playing conditions.

> Has it ever happened in the history of cricket?

In the history of cricket, probably, yes in some club match somewhere. I am not aware of any such incidents in professional cricket history though.